# Protractor script fails to execute on the android device

Tags: javascript, protractor, appium

My protractor config file looks like this:

```
var myHelper = require("./myHelper.js");
exports.config = {

  seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4723/wd/hub', of appium url
  chromeDriver: 'C:/appium/chromedriver',

  specs: ['tests/file1.js'],
  jasmineNodeOpts: {
    defaultTimeoutInterval: 180000,
  },
  prefs: {
      'profile.managed_default_content_settings.geolocation': 1,
      'profile.default_content_settings.popups':0
    },
  multiCapabilities: [
    {
      browserName: 'chrome',
      platformName: 'Android',
      platformVersion: '7.0',
      deviceName: 'ce10160a3538442705',
      'newCommandTimeout' : 120,

      'chromeOptions': {

        'args': ["--use-fake-ui-for-media-stream", '--use-fake-device-for-media-stream', '--disable-web-security','--start-maximized','--full-reset']
      },
    }
  ],

  onPrepare: function() {

    global.browsers = {
      a: (()=>{
        browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;
        return browser;
      })(),
      b: ()=> {
        var br = browser.forkNewDriverInstance(false, false);
        br.ignoreSynchronization = true;
        return br;
      },
      myHelper: myHelper
    };
  },
};
```

& running the appium using the following command:

appium -p 4723 -bp 4728 -U "ce10160a3538442705" --chromedriver-port 9516

When I run protractor conf.js, android device gets unlocked but the chrome browser is not launched and it again goes to unlock itself.

Logs:

```
[AndroidDriver] Using app unlock, this is going to be deprecated!
[AndroidDriver] Unlocking screen
[debug] [ADB] Getting connected devices...
[debug] [ADB] 1 device(s) connected
[debug] [ADB] Running 'C:\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe' with args: ["-P",5037,"-s","ce10160a3538442705","shell","am","force-stop","io.appium.unlock"]
[debug] [ADB] Device API level: 24
[debug] [ADB] Getting connected devices...
[debug] [ADB] 1 device(s) connected
[debug] [ADB] Running 'C:\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe' with args: ["-P",5037,"-s","ce10160a3538442705","shell","am","start","-W","-n","io.appium.unlock/.Unlock","-a","android.intent.action.MAIN","-c","android.intent.category.LAUNCHER","-f","0x10200000"]
[debug] [ADB] Device API level: 24
[debug] [ADB] Getting connected devices...
[debug] [ADB] 1 device(s) connected
[debug] [ADB] Running 'C:\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe' with args: ["-P",5037,"-s","ce10160a3538442705","shell","am","start","-W","-n","io.appium.unlock/.Unlock","-a","android.intent.action.MAIN","-c","android.intent.category.LAUNCHER","-f","0x10200000"]
[debug] [ADB] Getting connected devices...
[debug] [ADB] 1 device(s) connected
[debug] [ADB] Running 'C:\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe' with args: ["-P",5037,"-s","ce10160a3538442705","shell","dumpsys","window"]
[debug] [ADB] Getting connected devices...
[debug] [ADB] 1 device(s) connected
[debug] [ADB] Running 'C:\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe' with args: ["-P",5037,"-s","ce10160a3538442705","shell","dumpsys","window"]
[debug] [AndroidDriver] Shutting down Android driver
[debug] [ADB] Pressing the HOME button
[debug] [ADB] Getting connected devices...
[debug] [ADB] 1 device(s) connected
[debug] [ADB] Running 'C:\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe' with args: ["-P",5037,"-s","ce10160a3538442705","shell","input","keyevent",3]
[debug] [AndroidBootstrap] Sending command to android: {"cmd":"shutdown"}
[AndroidBootstrap] [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] Got data from client: {"cmd":"shutdown"}
[AndroidBootstrap] [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] Got command of type SHUTDOWN
[debug] [AndroidBootstrap] Received command result from bootstrap
[debug] [UiAutomator] Shutting down UiAutomator
[debug] [UiAutomator] Moving to state 'stopping'
[AndroidBootstrap] [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] Returning result: {"status":0,"value":"OK, shutting down"}
[AndroidBootstrap] [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] Closed client connection
[debug] [AndroidBootstrap] [UIAUTO STDOUT] INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS: numtests=1
[debug] [AndroidBootstrap] [UIAUTO STDOUT] INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS: stream=.
[debug] [AndroidBootstrap] [UIAUTO STDOUT] INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS: id=UiAutomatorTestRunner
[debug] [AndroidBootstrap] [UIAUTO STDOUT] INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS: test=testRunServer
[debug] [AndroidBootstrap] [UIAUTO STDOUT] INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS: class=io.appium.android.bootstrap.Bootstrap
[debug] [AndroidBootstrap] [UIAUTO STDOUT] INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS: current=1
[debug] [AndroidBootstrap] [UIAUTO STDOUT] INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS_CODE: 0
[debug] [AndroidBootstrap] [UIAUTO STDOUT] INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS: stream=
[debug] [AndroidBootstrap] [UIAUTO STDOUT] Test results for WatcherResultPrinter=.
[debug] [AndroidBootstrap] [UIAUTO STDOUT] Time: 449.159
[debug] [AndroidBootstrap] [UIAUTO STDOUT] OK (1 test)
[debug] [AndroidBootstrap] [UIAUTO STDOUT] INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS_CODE: -1
[debug] [UiAutomator] UiAutomator shut down normally
[debug] [UiAutomator] Moving to state 'stopped'
[debug] [ADB] Attempting to kill all uiautomator processes
[debug] [ADB] Getting all processes with uiautomator
[debug] [ADB] Getting connected devices...
[debug] [ADB] 1 device(s) connected
[debug] [ADB] Running 'C:\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe' with args: ["-P",5037,"-s","ce10160a3538442705","shell","ps"]
[ADB] No uiautomator process found to kill, continuing...
[debug] [UiAutomator] Moving to state 'stopped'
[debug] [Logcat] Stopping logcat capture
[debug] [ADB] Getting connected devices...
[debug] [ADB] 1 device(s) connected
[debug] [ADB] Running 'C:\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe' with args: ["-P",5037,"-s","ce10160a3538442705","shell","am","force-stop","io.appium.unlock"]
[debug] [AndroidDriver] Not cleaning generated files. Add `clearSystemFiles` capability if wanted.
[MJSONWP] Encountered internal error running command: Error: Screen did not unlock successfully, retrying
    at Object.callee$1$0$ (../../lib/android-helpers.js:453:13)
    at tryCatch (C:\Users\xxxx\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\appium\node_modules\babel-runtime\regenerator\runtime.js:67:40)
    at GeneratorFunctionPrototype.invoke [as _invoke] (C:\Users\xxxx\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\appium\node_modules\babel-runtime\regenerator\runtime.js:315:22)
    at GeneratorFunctionPrototype.prototype.(anonymous function) [as next] (C:\Users\xxxx\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\appium\node_modules\babel-runtime\regenerator\runtime.js:100:21)
    at GeneratorFunctionPrototype.invoke (C:\Users\xxxx\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\appium\node_modules\babel-runtime\regenerator\runtime.js:136:37)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:109:7)
[HTTP] <-- POST /wd/hub/session 500 463534 ms - 181
```

Comment: Do you have any error log?

Comment: Please find the attached logs.Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I figured the issue here. The device was set on auto lock after 30 secs because of which whenever it took appium around 30 secs to start, it was trying to unlock the device again.
I wonder if disabling auto lock all together is a good option.